# Windows Service Shutting Down from Control Panel Times Out

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows service written in C#/.net 4.0 to process some lengthy jobs implemented in my timer. I want to gracefully shut it down (wait all current jobs finish first). So I have following codes in my `OnStop` function

```
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        this.jobTimer.Enabled = false;

        while (TotalRunningJobs > 0)
        {
            this.RequestAdditionalTime(4000);
            t.Thread.Sleep(4000);
        }
    }
```

`TotalRunningJobs` variable is used to capture what happens inside the timer. With the codes above I got error message `Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.` if the job could not finish in time even I have used `RequestAdditionalTime` already.

Any idea why is that?

Comment: Have you tried requesting more time, or sleeping less? (i.e. RequestAdditionalTime(4000); Sleep(2000))

Is it possible you are not successfully requesting more time before the SCM times out?

Comment: @dodald it does not seem to help, it times out eventually.

Comment: I haven't not verified this myself, but it looks like the max additional time is 2 minutes.  http://corengen.wordpress.com/2009/12/18/the-limits-of-servicespipetimeout-and-servicebaserequestadditionaltime/

Comment: Have you timed your other jobs to make sure that they would all finish within the requested 4 seconds?

Comment: I did more testing, the Services in control panel will say time out, but the OS won't skill windows service at that point, it still waiting patiently until the windows service is actually shut down.